# SQL script - Counter of the number of times the user losses money in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please help us with some **SQL script** to solve the next problem:
We want to have a counter of the number of times the user losses money in a row until he wins again, bellow an example of the desire outcome:

[image]

10x!

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this?

Comment: whats your input data? a table with userID, gameID, timestamp and win/loss? the more data you provide, the easier it will be to help

Comment: `Select ..., case when winloss <0 then @Dout:=@Dout+1 else @Dout:=0 end as DesOutcome ... ORDER BY ROW` and initialize your user variable.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  This is not question, it is a requirement.  Please include what you have tried, etc.

Comment: the table is: Session_ID, User, Bet, Profit, Game and an indication if the player won or not. we tried using Row_number or Running sum but we lack what to use for the partition by.

Comment: are you using mysql? didn't knew there is Row_number too - bit this should be the solution

Comment: Yes @EstebanP. I`m using mysql, 10x for the help here :)

Comment: @DanielHonigsblum: i just posted a solution. i am not an expert in mysql, but it should work. have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the expert in MySQL, but the question seemed very intersting to me. 
For my testdata i just added a column timestamp, because pretty sure you have a column, with the information, when somebody played the game

My approach would be:

Creating some test-data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest
(
   game_timestamp datetime
  ,W_L_amount float
)
;

INSERT INTO mytest  (game_timestamp, W_L_amount)
VALUES
('2017-05-01', -5),
('2017-05-02', -9),
('2017-05-03', -8),
('2017-05-04', -7),
('2017-05-05', 5),
('2017-05-06', 9),
('2017-05-07', -8),
('2017-05-08', -6),
('2017-05-09', 5)
;
```

Solution:

```
 SELECT game_timestamp
       ,W_L_amount
       ,case when W_L_amount < 0 then @Ctr:=@Ctr+1 else @Ctr:=0 end as LossesInRow
   FROM mytest, (select @Ctr:=0, @rank=0) a
  order by game_timestamp
```

You can find a Rextester with the whole SQL-Statements here to reproduce it: http://rextester.com/YGNL13736

Comment: Working beautifully! 10x